# Angular DI and platformBrowserDynamic

Tags: angular

I am working on an existing Angular app and, still new to Angular, was trying to figure out how the dependency injection of a specific class was working.

Checking the [angular docs](https://angular.io/guide/dependency-injection), it mentions three ways make a dependency available:

- At the Component level, using the providers field of the @Component
  decorator
- At the NgModule level, using the providers field of the @NgModule
  decorator
- At the application root level, which allows injecting it into other
  classes in the application by adding the providedIn: 'root' field to
  the @Injectable decorator

The class I was looking at did not follow any of those three methods, rather it was included in a list of providers which was passed to `platformBrowserDynamic`:

```
platformBrowserDynamic(providers)...
```

I wasn't able to find documentation on what platformBrowserDynamic does with the list of providers, I just see that the classes are made available for DI.

Does platformBrowserDynamic end up somehow doing one of the three methods described in the Angular docs or is it some other internal functionality that serves the same purpose? Just trying to wrap my head around the big picture of what is going on.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When using `platformBrowserDynamic` the providers are passed to the platform injector.

The platformInjector resides above the root injector. Have a look at the doc about the [Platform injector](https://angular.io/guide/hierarchical-dependency-injection#platform-injector).